# Answers converted to comments should retain upvotes

Tags: feature-request, answers-as-comments

When the moderators convert some answers to comments based on flag requests from other users, I think it should also convert no. of upvotes to the **corresponding comment votes**.

Eg:- If an answer with 5 upvotes and 2 downvotes is converted to a comment, then the comment should get 3 upvotes automatically during conversion.

Since the comments do not have any downvote concept, the answers which get cummulative negative votes can be ignored when they are converted to comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a moderator uses the convert to comment feature, it means the provided answer **did not answer the question**. An answer that doesn't really answer the question should not receive any upvotes (assuming ideal voting behaviour). For that reason the feature is mostly used on answers with net zero or negative score.

Upvotes on answers and comments also have a slightly different meaning, I don't think they should be just transferred.

Comment: I have seen few answers which have been converted to comments and those answers have some upvotes. Unfortunately I do not have any samples to show. I agree when you say, the meaning of upvotes are different in comments, but its just a console for user when he is losing his upvotes for that answer and in-turn reducing his rep.

Comment: @Sachin That user shouldn't have had those upvotes to begin with; they're lucky they get to keep the rep until a recalc instead of just losing it immediately. And since they're generating work for people that have to convert their answers to comments, they're lucky they don't lose rep over it

Comment: @Michael - Well, I agree when you say those upvotes are lucky. My whole question was based on that assumption, but now since its clear that those posts should not have got upvotes, my feature-request would be needless. ;)

Comment: I just posted a question, [Up- and Down- voting on non-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209618/225437), that (I hope) shows one case where it might be reasonable to preserve upvotes on non-answers;  sometimes a non-answer is providing good solid debugging advice, so the upvotes are appropriate (according to the tooltip which says "This answer is useful"), but the answer isn't actually an answer (since it doesn't address the actual problem).  I'd probably be reasonable to transfer those kinds of upvotes to comment upvotes (since the "comment adds something useful to the post").

Comment: @Mad I disagree - I'm with Joshua: Upvotes for a non-answer are a strong indication that when converted to a comment, it will be a *good* comment. I think mods should be given the option (defaulting to "yes") when converting answers to comments to also convert a positive answer score to the comment upvote score (although upvote attribution would be a challenge in the case of both up and down votes on the answer).